# Python 2.6 numpy interaction array objects error

Tags: python, numpy

I have a multi-dimensional array of objects. I want to interate over the objects using the nditer iterator. 
Here is a code example:

```
import numpy as np

class Test:
    def __init__(self,a):
        self.a = a
    def get_a(self):
        return self.a

b = np.empty((2,3),dtype = object)

t_00 = Test(0)
t_01 = Test(1)
t_11 = Test (11)

b[0,0] = t_00
b[0,1] = t_01
b[1,1] = t_11

for item in np.nditer(b,flags = ["refs_ok"]):
    if item:
        print item.get_a()
```

I would expect the "item" to contain the object reference that I can use to access data.
However I am getting the following error:AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_a'
My question is how can I go thru the array to access the object in the array?

Comment: One issue I see in the code is that get_a needs to return self.a, not a.

Comment: You are right. However, I have the basic problem that I cannot access the "test object" at all. It seems that each "item" is referring to a numpy.ndarray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array.flat method of iteration will work, and can confirm that this works as you'd expect

```
for item in b.flat:
    if item:
        print item.get_a()
```

Comment: Thanks Jason! However I am still trying to find out how to use the nditer iterator. It works all right if I have an array with regular numbers. When I have objects, there is a problem. But I can see that nditer is reurning the right object address but may be with the wrong type.

Comment: Sadly this won't work if you intend to modify object array items.

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over an array with `nditer` gives you views of the original array's cells as 0-dimensional arrays. For non-object arrays, this is almost equivalent to producing scalars, since 0-dimensional arrays usually behave like scalars, but that doesn't work for object arrays.

If you were determined to go through `nditer` for this, you could extract the elements from the 0-dimensional views with the `item()` method:

```
for element in np.nditer(b,flags = ["refs_ok"]):
    element = element.item()
    if element:
        print(element.get_a())
```